# excel: button per row to copy & paste hidden row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a sheet with several rows, each with a '+' button. When the button is clicked, a "template" row that is hidden is copy&insert below the row of the button.

Comment: It makes little sense to have 1 button per row ! You can do the same thing with 1 single button, that will act on the active row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the hidden row is row 2 and that you only need a single button that will copy row 2 to the row below the active cell:

```
    Sub CopyRow
       Rows("2:2").Copy Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1)
    End sub
```

Comment: iDevlop's comment above is also very good advice.  Just have one button and have it act on the ActiveCell's rows.